# C++ inheritance virtual pure function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a problem dealing with an inheritance problem in the following code:

```
class Animal{
public:
    Animal(int age);
   ~Animal();
    virtual void print();  // problem here     
};

class cat : public Animal
{
public:
    cat(int age);
    ~cat();
    virtual void print();
};
cat::cat(int age) : Animal(age){}
cat::~cat(){}
void cat::print(){
    std::cout<<"I'm a cat "<<"My age is"<<this->getAge()<<std::endl;
}

int main (){
        farm f;
        cat c(3);
        dog d(4);
        f.add(c);
        f.add(d);
        c.print();
        f.print();
        std::cout<<f.getNa()<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
farm::farm(){

    this->na=0;
 }
void farm::add(Animal& a){
    if(this->na<10){
    this->ferme.push_back(a);
    this->na+=(*this).na;
    }
    else std::cout<<"la ferme est pleine"<<std::endl;
}
farm::~farm(){}
void farm::remove(){
    this->ferme.pop_back();
}
int farm::getNa(){
    return this->na;
}
void farm::print(){

    for(std::vector<Animal>::iterator it = this->ferme.begin();it !=this-   >ferme.end();++it){
        std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
        it->print();
    }
```

}
When I change `print` to `virtual void print()=0` to have a pure virtual function, I have several compilations problems. Whereas when I define the virtual function in `Animal` the print function of `cat` is no more considered.
yes  cat::print() is defined 
Here an example

among several other errors here one
error: 
      allocating an object of abstract class type 'Animal'
                ::new ((void*)__p) _Tp(__a0);
I'm sorry I'm new here

Comment: Is cat::print() defined?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/nrUscs) [either case](https://ideone.com/q5bFVM). Please always provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would help if you were specific about the errors you had when you made print() pure virtual.

Comment: I edited my post I'm a newbie ^^'

Comment: Did you add print() to dog?

Comment: I assume the error is in farm (since that would possibly use new) but you did not post that. The compiler should tell you what file it was compiling when it had a compile error.

Comment: You can not create a new Animal if you make print a pure virtual. You can however make a new dog or cat since print is defined in these.

Comment: I created only dog and cat which inherit from animal

Comment: Your problem is `std::vector<Animal>`. You can not define that like that because Animal can not be instantiated.

Comment: why it's a problem? I mean without virtual void print()=0; the code works fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: Animal can not be instantiated because of the pure virtual. So you can not have a vector of Animals. You can have a vector of std::shared_ptr<Animal> however. Or if you do not know about smart pointers (and not permitted to use them because of a homework restriction) std::vector<Animal*> but then you have to handle the deletion of the Animals otherwise there will be memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should define virtual void print() in cat.cpp class.

```
//Example for cat.cpp class
#include "cat.h"
cat:cat(int age){
cat::age = age;
}
void cat::print(){
std::cout << getAge();
```

Comment: I did that but If I implement Animal::print() cat::print() is not considered and I if I don't I have error virtual method not implemented even though I wrote virtual void Animal::print()=0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your `farm` class you have a member of type `std::vector<Animal>`. You may think you're inserting your `cat` or `dog` objects in this vector, but you're not. If it's defined as:

```
std::vector<Animal> ferme;
```

then it can only contain `Animal` instances.

This is why if you make the `Animal` class abstract (make `print` pure virtual) it will fail to build.

This is also why if you implement the `print` method in `Animal` it ignores the print methods in `cat` and `dog`. The `it->print()` call in your `farm::print` method is applied to an `Animal` instance, so the correct method to call is the one from `Animal`.

The virtual dispatch mechanism only works with pointers or references, e.g.:

```
Animal *a1 = new cat(10);
a1->print(); // will call cat::print()

cat c1(10);
Animal &a2 = c1;
a2.print(); // will call cat::print()

Animal a3 = c1; // like you do when inserting in the vector
a3.print(); // will call Animal::print()
```